# Retrofit: How to resolve requests duplications

Tags: android, android-networking

recently I started to develop using Retrofit and could immediately notice that it doesn't provides some important features such as - retries, certification handling, prioritisation and more.

I was manage to implement the prioritisation and retries myself but encounter a harder problem to solve.

I want to manage to "catch" the network requests before they are getting to the executer's queue in order to avoid the same requests over and over again.

For ex. user sometimes can pull to refresh 5 times one after another and I do not want to invoke 5 identical request. The check for identically request is easy - same domain with same parameters.

Here is my implementation:

```
// the thread factory of the thread pool, we using it to indicate the threads' priority
    ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setPriority(threadPriority);
            return t;
        }
    };

    mQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
    mExecuter = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT, mQueue);

    mExecuter.setThreadFactory(threadFactory);

    mRestAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setClient(new AndroidApacheClient()).setExecutors(mExecuter, mExecuter)
            .setEndpoint(NetworkContants.DOMAIN).setRequestInterceptor(mRequestInterceptor).setConverter(new GsonConverter(new Gson()))
            .build();
```

Comment: any solution for your problem

Answer (score 1):

You could block executing more requests with flagging, which is trivial.

Have a class like this one: Make sure you type it properly.

```
public class CheckableCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private boolean isRunning;

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean isRunning) {
        this.isRunning = isRunning;
    }


    @Override
    public void success(T t, Response response) {
        setRunning(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        setRunning(false);

    }
}
```

Before you execute it check if, the callback is running:

```
if(!mRefreshingCallback.isRunning()){
  //execute 
  mRefreshingCallback.setRunning(true);
}
```

Comment: The callback is getting executed only after the request finishes. I don't want the request to be even entered to the threadPoolExecuter's queue if the same request already exists there. The code here is irrelevant

Comment: You execute (add to the threadexecutor) it only if it has finished or failed. I.e if the condition passed.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you disallow the pull to refresh if its refreshing? Wouldn't it make sense not to allow an a request until you receive a response in place of queuing?

Comment: It's an option, but I was looking for a fix in the backend level of the app, not the frontend level. Meaning - I want an architecture fix and not to have workaround wherever I find it useful